# Ion-input of type "date" has calendar icon of the wrong color

Tags: css, date, ionic-framework, input, ionicons

I have an ion-input field with type=" date". The ion-input automatically gets a calendar icon with the corresponding functionality. The only thing is that everything is white in my application, but I can't seem to get this icon to turn white.

**It just likes to stay black**

[image: ion-input]

Does anybody know the solution to getting this icon in a different (white) color?

**All help is appreciated**

Answer (score 1):

This isn't part of ionic but rather the native html element. In this case to change this we put the css in the global.scss file. So it would affect all date type input fields.

This css inverts the color of the date icon to make it white:

```
.native-input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

If you don't want it to affect all input fields we need to get this specific input field in JS and change it's css there.

Comment: I did not manage to get this to work. Let's just say I only have one and therefore only need to affect this one. Maybe you can instruct me just a little bit better?

Comment: Also when I view it on an actual android device I don't even get to see the placeholder and the icon, although I don't see these it still works so I guess I will not bother anymore.